# Wait for all threads to finish

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I would like to process a filesystem/folder for subdirectories and files in C#. I'm using Tasks from the TPL library. The idea is to do it recursively and create for every folder a task. The main thread should wait for the child threads to finish and then print some info. In fact I just want to know when scanning is finished. I have started with threadpool, then switched to TLP. Did some easy examples. after some tries from simple code to more and more bloated code I'm stuck here:

```
private Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public MediaObjectFolder MediaObjectFolder { get; set; }
private Queue<MediaObjectFolder> Queue { get; set; }

private object quelock, tasklock;
private List<Task> scanTasks;

public IsoTagger()
{
    quelock = new object();
    tasklock = new object();
    scanTasks = new List<Task>();

    MediaObjectFolder = new MediaObjectFolder(@"D:\Users\Roman\Music\Rock\temp");
    Queue = new Queue<MediaObjectFolder>();
}

public MediaObject RescanFile(string fullpath, string filename)
{
    return new MediaObject(fullpath);
}

public void Rescan()
{
    Queue.Clear();

    lock (tasklock)
    {
        Task scanFolderTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(ScanFolder, MediaObjectFolder);
        scanTasks.Add(scanFolderTask);
    }

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(scanTasks.ToArray(), (ant) =>
        {
            if (log != null)
            {
                log.Debug("scan finished");
                log.Debug("number of folders: {0}", Queue.Count);
            }

        });
}

private void ScanFolder(object o)
{
    List<Task> subTasks = new List<Task>();

    MediaObjectFolder mof = o as MediaObjectFolder;
    log.Debug("thread - " + mof.Folder);

    string[] subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(mof.Folder);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(mof.Folder, "*.mp3");


    foreach(string dir in subdirs)
    {
        log.Debug(dir);

        MediaObjectFolder tmp = new MediaObjectFolder(dir);
        lock (tasklock)
        {
            Task tmpTask = new Task(ScanFolder, tmp);
            subTasks.Add(tmpTask);
        }
    }

    foreach (Task tsk in subTasks)
    {
        tsk.Start();
    }

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        log.Debug(file);

        MediaObject tmp = new MediaObject(file);
        MediaObjectFolder.MediaObjects.Add(tmp);
    }

    lock (quelock)
    {
        Queue.Enqueue(mof);
    }

    if (subTasks != null)
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(subTasks.ToArray(), logTask => log.Debug("thread release - " + mof.Folder));
}
```

Main thread still sometimes continues too early and not after finishing of all other threads. (I'm relatively new to C# and not an expert in parallel programming too, so there might be some heavy-weight concept errors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general approach that you're taking inherently makes this a fairly hard problem to solve.  Instead, you can simply use the file system methods to traverse the hierarchy for you, and then use PLINQ to process those files in parallel effectively:

```
var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*"
    , SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var query = directories.AsParallel().Select(dir =>
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.mp3"
        , SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    //TODO create custom object and add files
});
```

Comment: i'll take a look at it. would it work for a lot of directories? i mean i'm interested in +25000 files in about 3000 directories. but i'll take a look at the directory functions too...

Comment: @rome Sure it would.  The directories are enumerated lazily, as they are requested, and they are parallelized based on a scheduler that is going to optimize throughput.

Comment: I'm trying it... Thx! as soon as it works, i'll mark it as the answer ;-)

Comment: thx for your suggestions, i finally came up with my own solution, but the hint of directory and file enumeration was very valuable

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to research the Task.WaitAll and Task.WaitAny methods.  There is example code here: [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For the quick answer:

```
Task.WaitAll(subTasks);
```

should work for you.

Comment: Those, by themselves, are not going to be sufficient here.  He doesn't know, when he first starts, what all of the tasks that need to be waited on are.

Comment: He only needs to wait on the tasks after he has completed the start() of all of them, i.e., after the recursive function returns. 

Otherwise, he is still creating new tasks and isn't concerned with completed tasks yet.

Comment: But that function only finishes starting the tasks; they aren't done when it returns, and those tasks are going to start *more* tasks, thanks to the recursion.  Your proposal would ensure that all of the top level directories were handled, but not the sub directories.

Comment: Ok, if each of his threads Wait on all of the threads they create, the problem fixes itself.  The main() can still just wait on the threads it created and they will, in turn wait on their child threads.  Then everyone wins. ;-)

Comment: Then you lose all asynchrony, which is the point of using tasks in the first place (to avoid blocking waits).  In any case, this answer is completely inadequate.  As I said in my first comment, while this is a tool that may be used in solving the problem, it's not obvious how it should be used *in this context*, so an answer would need to describe how it should be used.

Comment: I just saw your solution.  Much better for the given problem! Thanks for your constructive criticism as well.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

after good suggestions by Servy and further research about Parallelism in C# i came up with an answer to my question.
As i don't really need LINQ for this simple task, where i just want to enumerate my filesystem and process the folders parallel.

```
public void Scan()
{
    // ...
    // enumerate all directories under one root folder (mof.Folder)
    var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(mof.Folder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    // use parallel foreach from TPL to process folders
    Parallel.ForEach(directories, ProcessFolder);
    // ...
}

private void ProcessFolder(string folder)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("root folder does not exist!");
    }
    MediaObjectFolder mof = new MediaObjectFolder(folder);
    IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.mp3", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        MediaObject mo = new MediaObject(file);
        mof.MediaObjects.Add(mo);
    }
    lock (quelock)
    {
         // add object to global queue
         Enqueue(mof);
    }
}
```

after a quite an intensive research i found this as the easiest solution. please note: i haven't done any tests if this approach is faster, as i work on a temp file base which is not really big. this is also the way described in the MSDN library for parallel processing of the filesystem.

PS: there is also a lot of space for improvement of performance